# Timestamp date format impossible to convert to float

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, timestamp

I've being trying to convert the date below from Timestamp to float. I have already tried all functions in all orders (fromtimestamp, strftime, strptime, .date()... etc etc etc) and nothing. I have also read all related questions available on google and none works for me. Anyone could please help?

The closest to a solution I got is the code below and the error states: "TypeError: an integer is required (got type Timestamp)" and I quit confident that other errors will pop up after this.

The imported file can be found here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/oe0h7mu2k0vwpn2/Linx%20Revenues.xls?dl=0

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

#Upload Data
df = pd.read_excel("Linx Revenues.xls")

#Rename Columns
df.columns = ['Date', 'Gross']

#Adjust Dates

for index, row in df.iterrows():

df['Date'][index] = datetime.datetime(df['Date'][index], '%d/%m/%y').date().strftime('%d/%m/%Y')             
df["Date"][index] = float(datetime.strptime(df["Date"][index], '%d/%m/%Y').date().strftime('%Y%m%d'))
```

Comment: How does it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) for string format with [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) for convert to `float`:

```
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], '%d/%m/%Y').dt.strftime('%Y%m%d').astype(float)
```

Solution with your real data is simplify, because is not necessary convert to datetimes:

```
df = pd.read_excel('Linx Revenues.xls')
df.columns = ['Date', 'Gross']
#print (df)

df["Date"] = df["Date"].dt.strftime('%Y%m%d').astype(float)
print (df)
          Date    Gross
0   20171201.0   168.40
1   20171201.0   188.60
2   20171201.0   177.40
3   20171201.0   958.90
4   20171201.0   931.90
5   20171201.0    71.80
6   20171201.0    35.00
7   20171201.0   556.13
8   20171201.0   413.00
9   20171201.0     0.90
10  20171201.0   699.00
11  20171201.0   111.70
12  20171201.0   153.30
13  20171201.0   669.10
14  20171201.0   713.70
15  20171201.0   423.70
16  20171201.0    -2.00
17  20171202.0    80.50
18  20171202.0   213.40
19  20171202.0  1170.10
20  20171202.0   605.00
21  20171202.0  1275.30
22  20171202.0   202.30
23  20171202.0   120.00
```

Comment: Jezrael, you are a genious! Great and simple solution. How can I send you a symbolic gift for your kindness?

Comment: Tks to you Jezrael